# How to change Postgres JDBC driver properties to change return class on count function?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jasper-reports

I am running a Jasper report (via an jrxml), I am connecting / reading from a Postgres database. 
The Sql returns a value from a count function, this then causes java.lang.ClassCastException when writing this value to the Jasper report (via an xml), can I amend the JDBC driver properties to handle this (rather than amend the sql).

The line in the SQL that caused the error was

```
COALESCE(B.GP_COUNT,0) as GP_COUNT
```

If I amend the line that populates GP_COUNT using a CAST statement then this works OK in the xml:-

```
CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT PD_CDE) AS INT4) AS GP_COUNT
```

I am looking for a solution that avoids changes to the xml’s & jrxml’s (as we have hundreds of reports to convert to Postgres from DB2)

Any help appreciated, I am not a java person so I apologise in advance.

Comment: we have a lot of reports to amend from DB2 to Postgres, so was looking for a generic fix (rather than amending lots of xmls / jrxml's) thanks

Comment: cast in the query does fix it, but is there a "global" solution where we could tweak the driver that will allow all the xmls to work (without changing the queries), thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Show the jrxml related to $F{GP_COUNT}, what is class declaration?, in comment you state cast from Long --> Integer, in question String, I think you have Integer in field declaration and the solution is to change all these to Long, since Integer is wrong.

Comment: That would fix it, but we have hundreds of reports to swtich from DB2 to Postgres, was looking for a high level solution that would avoid sql & report changes (if possible)

Comment: I don't think there exist any driver settings to change the sql Types returned by meta data call (seems also strange to do so), the only solution would be to implement your own driver ;), I would changed the field declaration to Long, it's incorrect to have Integer on a count field (since it could overflow)

Comment: Ok thanks for the help @PetterFriberg, Laurenz Albe

Answer (score 1):

The PostgreSQL JDBC Driver does *not* return a string, but a `BIGINT` as result of the `count` aggregate function.

This Java code:

```java
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
java.sql.Connection conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(
                                "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/mydb?user=myuser"
                            );
java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
java.sql.ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM pg_class");
System.out.println("Type of count(*) is a BIGINT: "
                 + (rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(1) == java.sql.Types.BIGINT)
                );
rs.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

produces:

```
Type of count(*) is a BIGINT: true
```

Comment: Maybe it's when the data is written to the report if fails:-   Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
 Source text : $F{GP_COUNT}
 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
 at CIRDispensingPracticeNameAddress_1430237118595_540206.evaluate(CIRDispensingPracticeNameAddress_1430237118595_540206:692)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:231)
 ... 84 more

Comment: @MartinG so your field is java.lang.Integer?, where did the String stuff come from?

Comment: this is the command that caused the error   ,COALESCE(B.GP_COUNT,0) as GP_COUNT, so I assumed that a string value was passign in to the report causing the error

Comment: @MartinG update your question with all these information, full command, full exception and jrxml related to field declaration.

Comment: @PetterFriberg The metadata say that it returns a `BIGINT`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yeah that's the problem he has Integer class in jrxml declaration, that worked fine DB, but PostgreSQL, returns BIGINT, that is a Long, hence the error. I highly doubt you can set some driver properties to change to Integer. The solution here is to modify the query or modify the field declaration to Long (this would also work with DB2)